# Putting a string in pointer of array

Tags: c++, c, string

I want to assign a string like: `"22 33"` to a variable like `char*av[129]`. How can i do that in C/C++?

Comment: those types are incompatible -- a single string vs. an array of strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strcpy(av[0], "22 33");
```

**IF** you know `av[0]` is long enough (length of string you want to put in plus one for the `NUL`).

Otherwise, use `strncpy`.

Comment: He should always use `strncpy`, even only as a good habit. Also, it won't solve his problem if the buffer isn't long enough - it would just change the bug, perhaps to a friendlier one.